# Python runtime warning when move unit test to a package

Tags: python, unit-testing, import

When I write a unit test at the root folder of the project, everything works fine. But, when I moved the unit test file to /test package, a warning message is shown up. Do you know what does warning means and how I resolve it.

test/MotorTest.py

MotorStub.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import unittest
from MotorStub import MotorStub

motor = MotorStub()

class MotorTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_rotate(self):
        self.assertEqual(motor.rotate("right"),0)
```

Warnings:

RuntimeWarning: Parent module 'test' not found while handling absolute import
  from MotorStub import MotorStub

RuntimeWarning: Parent module 'test' not found while handling absolute import
  import unittest